# command to return version of ur5

Tags: ros, ur-modern-driver, universal-robot, ur5, ur-driver

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple question. How do I know which version of UR5 am I running? I am currently attempting to launch a moveit package for a UR5 arm but am running into issues launching the package because depending on the ur version that I am running I need to determine whether to be using the `ur_driver` or `ur_modern_driver`.

Some other forum explained:
For system versions ranging from v1.5.7849 to v1.8.23117 I can use the ur_driver.
Beyond v3.x you need to use the ur_modern_driver.

**I don't quite now which version I am running however and need to know if there is a command to figure out which ur version my arm is running?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268097/command-to-return-version-of-ur5/) by [maxgitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/30480/maxgitt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

simply open the UI and the top left corner returns a small window about the system settings.

---

Originally posted by [maxgitt](https://answers.ros.org/users/30480/maxgitt/) with karma: 18 on 2017-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0